# Calculate the date after 6 months from compare the date of database using java

Tags: java

i want to send an auto mail after every 6 months from the registration date.
i am using CornJob for this auto mail.

now i am collecting date from database and want to get that date after 6 months.

(`now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1`) this will increment month to `5` month, but what if current month in 9(sep.).

how can i get that date after `6` months ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're doing, or where the database comes in... but you can use

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
```

to add 6 months to a `Calendar` value. Is that what you're after?

In general, I would recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `Calendar` / `Date` for date and time calculations, just because it's simpler - but without more information about how your code fits together, it's hard to know whether that's appropriate in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

not sure how are SQL-92 standards implemeted for all SQL Interpreters [DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/DATEADDcurdateINTERVAL1MONTH.htm),