# How to Increment date type value like Calendar Type

Tags: java, mysql, date, calendar

I am newbie to java, I want to add a Date type in table's column  using native query.
But I have to increment my time by x minutes and then add.
In java :
we have `calendar.add()` method but I have to insert in Database as Date type

Here's the sample code :

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60*48);
```

But in DB I have to insert Date type as :
here:

```
Date  currentTime = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
ResultSet resultset = obdnumberbo.getlist(userCallDetail.getaPartyMsisdn(),userCallDetail.getbPartyMsisdn(),currentTime,Jobname);
```

I want to do something with `currenTime` and increment it like add() method in Calendar class.
Also there is no way to cast calendar type object into date type.

Can anyone suggest a way?

Can any one suggest how to do this?

Comment: Use the [`Calendar.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) method to get the equivalent `Date` object.

Comment: A tip when adding/subtracting calendar is to make sure calendar is in non lenient mode by calling setLenient(false). This is to ensure you get valid dates only.

Comment: You can also use JodaTime library for Date manipulation. For example: `DateTime.now().plusMinutes(1).toDate();`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to increment a Java.sql.date / time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977316/what-is-the-best-way-to-increment-a-java-sql-date-time) and of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7512669/642706).